# AbstractMethodError: org.apache.bval.jsr303.ConfigurationImpl has missing definition for method getDefaultParameterNameProvider()

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, java-11, abstractmethoderror

I am currently working on upgrading our Spring Boot (2.1.5) Application to gradle version '5.4.1' with JAVA 11.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultValidator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.apache.bval.jsr303.ConfigurationImpl does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider; of interface javax.validation.Configuration.
```

Relevant Dependencies:

hibernate-core: 5.4.3.Final

hibernate-validator: 6.0.17.Final

I have tried downgrading hibernate-validator and tried explicitly specifying a version of validation-api but nothing seems to work.

Build.Gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.5.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = '11'
    targetCompatibility = '11'
}
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'idea'

mainClassName = 'io.app.ams.Application'

bootJar {
    mainClassName 'io.app.ams.Application'
    launchScript()
}

springBoot {
    mainClassName 'io.app.ams.Application'
    buildInfo()
}

bootRun {
    sourceResources sourceSets.main
}

apply from: 'liquibase.gradle'
apply from: 'gatling.gradle'

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

defaultTasks 'bootRun'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
    maven { url 'https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases' }
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases' }
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
    maven { url 'http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2' }

    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation')
    testImplementation 'org.scalatest:scalatest_2.11:3.0.0'
    compile group: 'commons-httpclient', name: 'commons-httpclient', version: '3.1'
    compile group: 'io.dropwizard.metrics', name: 'metrics-core'
    compile group: 'io.dropwizard.metrics', name: 'metrics-graphite'
    compile group: 'io.dropwizard.metrics', name: 'metrics-healthchecks'
    compile group: 'io.dropwizard.metrics', name: 'metrics-jvm', version: dropwizard_metrics_version
    compile group: 'io.dropwizard.metrics', name: 'metrics-servlet', version: dropwizard_metrics_version
    compile group: 'io.dropwizard.metrics', name: 'metrics-json', version: dropwizard_metrics_version
    compile group: 'io.dropwizard.metrics', name: 'metrics-servlets'

    // kafka
    compile group: 'org.springframework.kafka', name: 'spring-kafka', version: kafka_version

    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-s3', version: '1.11.18'

    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-json-org', version: jackson_version
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-hppc', version: jackson_version
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-joda'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-hibernate4', version: jackson_version
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jdk8'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module', name: 'jackson-module-parameter-names'

    compile(group: 'com.zaxxer', name: 'HikariCP', version: HikariCP_version) {
        exclude(module: 'tools')
    }

    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: commons_lang_version
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: commons_io_version
    compile group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version: javax_inject_version
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '4.0.1'

    compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.10.2'

    compile group: 'org.apache.geronimo.javamail', name: 'geronimo-javamail_1.4_mail', version: geronimo_javamail_1_4_mail_version

    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.4.3.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate.validator', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '6.1.0.Alpha5'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-envers', version: '5.4.3.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-ehcache' ,version: '5.4.3.Final'

    compile group: 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence', name: 'hibernate-jpa-2.1-api', version: '1.0.2.Final'

    compile group: 'org.jadira.usertype', name: 'usertype.core', version: '7.0.0.CR1'

    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-parent', version: '2.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version: '2.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-properties-migrator', version: '2.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-autoconfigure'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-loader-tools'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-aop'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security'

    compile(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.1.6.RELEASE')
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-websocket'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-velocity', version: '1.1.3.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch', version: '2.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'

    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-spring-service-connector'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-localconfig-connector'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-config', version: '2.1.3.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-dependencies', version: 'Greenwich.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix', version: '2.1.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul', version: '2.1.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot', version: '2.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '5.1.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context-support'

    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-core', version: spring_security_version
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-config', version: spring_security_version
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-data', version: spring_security_version
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-web', version: spring_security_version
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-messaging', version: spring_security_version
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-acl', version: spring_security_version
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security.oauth', name: 'spring-security-oauth2', version: spring_security_oauth2_version

    compile group: 'org.springframework.ws', name: 'spring-ws-core', version: '3.0.7.RELEASE'

    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.16'
    compile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2'
    compile group: 'org.kairosdb', name: 'client', version: '3.0.0'
    compile group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: lombok_version
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: commons_lang3_version
    compile group: 'commons-validator', name: 'commons-validator', version: commons_validator_version
    compile group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version: jjwt_version

    runtime "net.java.dev.jna:jna"

    optional "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springBootVersion}"
        mavenBom 'org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:5.1.8.RELEASE'
    }
}

compileJava.dependsOn(processResources)

wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '5.4.1'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

Comment: Please share the pom.xml file

Comment: can you please include the dependency tree?

Comment: Hi, i have attached the build.gradle file, i have cleaned it up a bit since it has huge dependency stack.

Answer (score 1):

The error is linked to bval (apache bean validation implementation), the one you have targets bean validation 1.0. you can upgrade it to bval-jsr for a bean validation 1.1 implementation or exclude/drop it if you want hibernate instead.

Side note: if you are in an old tomee it requires some system.properties tuning if i recall correctly.

Comment: I had to rename my javax.validation1.1 jar to something like ijavax.validation1.1, so that it gets loaded alphabetically before loading javaEE6 jar from the lib path. As both jars contain the same package structure, like javax.validation.spi